# How to combine Percentile and Median in Python?

Tags: python

My dataframe called **df_results**

It looks like this

```
Cust     Code   Price
=====================
1        A      98
1        B      25
1        C      74
1        D      55
1        E      15
1        F      32
1        G      71
2        A      10
2        K      52
2        M      33
2        S      14
99       K      10
99       N      24
99       S      26
99       A      49
99       W      50
99       J      52
99       Q      55
99       U      68
99       C      73
99       Z      74
99       P      82
99       E      92
 
.        .      .
.        .      .
.        .      .
```

I am trying to break each customer prices into categories per percntile

```
Cust 99  prices are  10 24 26 49 50 52 55 68 73 74 82 92
```

Therefore for this customer the

```
25% ==> 31.75
50% ==> 53.5
75% ==> 73.75
100% ==> 92
```

Prices for each customer have to be averaged as per the percentile it belongs to

```
Cust  Code Price  Perctile   Perce_Value     Perc_Avg
=====================================================
99     K   10     25%        31.75           20
99     N   24     25%        31.75           20
99     S   26     25%        31.75           20
99     A   49     50%        53.5            50.33
99     W   50     50%        53.5            50.33
99     J   52     50%        53.5            50.33
99     Q   55     75%        73.75           65.33
99     U   68     75%        73.75           65.33
99     C   73     75%        73.75           65.33
99     Z   74     100%       92              82.66
99     P   82     100%       92              82.66
99     E   92     100%       92              82.66
```

I managed to do that through multiple looping through the dataframe

which is not effecient and I believe there must be a better solution.

Is there a better way to do that?

## EDIT

I tried using lambda function

Step 1 : to fine Percentile_Value

```
df_results["Percentile_Value"] = df_results.apply(lambda x: np.percentile(x["Price"],25), axis=1)
```

but this did not give me any value , it just repeated **Price** into **Percentile_Value** as is

Comment: Show how you did it to produce a result. The prose is not as clear as you think.

Comment: What's wrong with just sorting the data?

Comment: How did you compute your percentile values? If `100%=92` then why isn't `25%=23`?

Comment: @Nick prices in the first percentile (25%) are the prices less than 31.75  ..... while 2nd percentile (50%) are prices less than 53.5  .... prices in 3rd percntile (75%) are prices less than 73.75 ..... prices in the 4th percentile (100%) are prices less than 92

Comment: but how did you get 31.75 for the 25th percentile?

Comment: @Nick mistake 43.25